# Upgrade RHL 7.6 to RHL 7.7, strange error

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, yum

I am upgrading RHL 7.6 to 7.7 but I encounter strange error.

```
$>uname -r
3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64

$>yum update
Loaded plugins: enabled_repos_upload, package_upload, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
rhel-7-server-extras-rpms                                                                                                               
rhel-7-server-optional-rpms                                                                                                             
rhel-7-server-satellite-tools-6.4-rpms                                                                                                  
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package diffutils.x86_64 0:3.3-4.el7 will be updated
---> Package diffutils.i686 0:3.3-5.el7 will be an update
---> Package libdb-cxx.x86_64 0:5.3.21-24.el7 will be updated
---> Package libdb-cxx.i686 0:5.3.21-25.el7 will be an update
--> Processing Dependency: libdb(x86-32) = 5.3.21-25.el7 for package: libdb-cxx-5.3.21-25.el7.i686
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: libdb-cxx-5.3.21-25.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-optional-rpms)
           Requires: libdb(x86-32) = 5.3.21-25.el7
**********************************************************************
yum can be configured to try to resolve such errors by temporarily enabling
disabled repos and searching for missing dependencies.
To enable this functionality please set 'notify_only=0' in /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/search-disabled-repos.conf
**********************************************************************

Error: Package: libdb-cxx-5.3.21-25.el7.i686 (rhel-7-server-optional-rpms)
           Requires: libdb(x86-32) = 5.3.21-25.el7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
Uploading Enabled Repositories Report
Loaded plugins: product-id, subscription-manager
```

Although `yum check` is clean, `yum check-update` gives me that:

```
$>yum check-update
Loaded plugins: enabled_repos_upload, package_upload, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
rhel-7-server-extras-rpms                                                                                                               
rhel-7-server-optional-rpms                                                                                                                
rhel-7-server-satellite-tools-6.4-rpms                                                                                                  

diffutils.i686 (this one is white color)                        3.3-5.el7                                                       rhel-7-server-optional-rpms
libdb-cxx.i686                                                  5.3.21-25.el7                                                   rhel-7-server-optional-rpms
Uploading Enabled Repositories Report
Loaded plugins: product-id, subscription-manager
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I reviewed  `/etc/yum.repos.d/redhat.repo` .. I noticed I am missing the "`rhel-7-server-rpms/7Server/x86_64`" repo. After I added it and everything worked.